# Can I use a jailbroken iPhone on Virgin Mobile?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I am no longer on a contract with AT&T. Virgin Mobile has an awesome Beyond Talk plan for $25 (unlimited text, data, web, well I guess a max of 5.5Gb). Can I use a SIM card from a Virgin Mobile phone on my jailbroken iPhone?

Also, is it possible to buy just a SIM card from Virgin?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Virgin Mobile is a part of Sprint (they used to be a Sprint MVNO). Sprint uses CDMA, not GSM, so they do not have SIM cards.

So, no iPhone on Sprint at least until Apple makes a CDMA iPhone and sells them for Sprint.

Comment: In UK Virgin Mobile is on T-Mobile and is GSM so will it work in UK?

Comment: Virgin Mobile is completely separate companies in different countries, usually a joint venture (or that countries' legal system's similar construct) between Virgin Group (or a local subsidiary) and the target cell carrier (Sprint in the US, T-Mobile in the UK). I felt it safe to assume that the asker was US-based as they referenced AT&T.

Comment: Yes, it is physically possible on Virgin Mobile UK assuming they usually handle GSM phones.